# ModX Revo: Database map

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Would anyone know where I would be able to find a 'map' of the ModX Revo database? IE: the relationships between tables?

Ive Googled, searched SO and Modx's documentation and came up nothing!

Thanks - any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/develop/core/model/schema/modx.mysql.schema.xml - this is scheme of all tables. But to understand it will have to learn some xpdo.

UPD: You can visualize this schema by using http://schemaviewer.dev.kenters.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use navicat to get a graphical representation of the database tables ~ however the relations are defined in the xpdo schema and not the database itself.  Your best bet is to use Vasis's link to the XML schema which will actually be very easy to follow.

You might also ask in the modx forums if they have such a thing for their own reference... the devs are in there all the time.